# Add maximizebox and minimizebox RibbonControl Dotnetbar

Tags: c#, windows-forms-designer, ribbon-control, dotnetbar

First I'm working in C# with Windows Forms, I have a question about how can I add the maximizebox and minimizebox to RibbonControl, what is the property that let me add this buttons, tell me if I can do it from designer or the code to do that. Thanks

Comment: Did you put in any effort yourself trying to solve the problem?

Comment: Yes, I did, but I don't know find the way

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the way, the propertys of MinimizeBox and MaximizeBox in the form could be in true and automatically the RibbonControl Add boxes to the control